# Make rails carousel image a hyperlink

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to click on one of the images in my bootstrap carousel and have it redirect to another page on my site. Unfortunately I keep getting errors with it.

Here is the html/erb

**This code does not function!**

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <%=link_to "#{image_tag("rsz_adobestock_44582832.jpg", :alt => "Slide1"), {:class => "img-responsive", :alt => "Responsive image"}}".html_safe, services_path %>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>
```

I'm doing something similar with the logo in the navbar, and that works fine.. Here is the code for that

***This code functions perfectly***

```
      <div class="navbar-brand-image"> <%=link_to "#{image_tag 'rsz_1rsz_13logo.png'}".html_safe ,root_path %></div>
```

Finally, here is the error that I get with the code for the carousel.

```html
/app/views/home/home.html.erb:17: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting tSTRING_DEND
...582832.jpg", :alt => "Slide1"), {:class => "img-responsive",...
...                               ^):
  app/views/home/home.html.erb:17: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting tSTRING_DEND
```

Comment: I'm going to be provocative and recommend that you don't use a carousel as a UI element: http://shouldiuseacarousel.com/

Comment: unfortunately not my decision. I'm just responsible for making it work

Comment: then you have my full sympathy sir/madam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this

```
 <%= link_to(image_tag('rsz_adobestock_44582832.jpg',:alt => "Slide1", :class => "img-responsive"), services_path)%>
```

but please check if there is a image exist.

Comment: The code for the navbar works fine, its the top block of code that i've included that is giving me trouble and i'm not sure why